# Как массово изменить структуру кода и проитерировать числа в нем?

Tags: php, html

Всем доброй ночи.

Имеется такой html код:

```
<div class="test" title="Подсказка"><span><img src="/images.png" alt="картинка"></span><span>Текст</span></div>
```

Таких строк есть порядка 800 штук (все они однотипны) меняется только "Подсказка", "/images.png" и "Текст"

Сейчас возникла необходимость изменить структуру, на такую:

```
<div class="test"><span>#1</span><span><img src="/images.png" alt="картинка"></span><span>Текст</span><span>Подсказка</span></div>
```

Возможно ли это сделать на автомате? или придется все переделывать ручками?

Comment: Да можно, скриптик просто написать и прогнать через него твои 800 строк. Он распарсит и вставит что надо и куда надо.  Пхп причем тут неизвестно, возможно связано с тем, что что-то недосказано.

Comment: Да вроде это можно в обычном notepad++ поиск-замена регуляркой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что `#1` - это итерационный элемент, т.е. для него нужно в каждом последующем случае делать +1.

Написал вам скрипт, где некий файл **file.html** (вы можете самостоятельно изменить название файла) приводится к нужной вам структуре и сохраняется в файл **fileNew.html** . Для того, чтобы запустить скрипт, нужно, чтобы у вас был установлен пхп, далее вам нужно в папку где содержится этот **file.html** поместить этот скрипт (к примеру, создать файл php.php) и запустить его (например, вызвать через браузер адрес типа: `http://ваш_сайт.ру/папка_где_лежит_хтмл/php.php` .

```
<?php
$file = __DIR__.'/file.html';
$text = file_get_contents($file);

$pattern = '/<div class="test" title="([^"]+)"><span>(<img [^>]+>)<\/span><span>(.*?)<\/span><\/div>/imsu';

$_GET['i'] = 0;
$textNew = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'myReplace', $text);

function myReplace($matches) {
    $_GET['i']++;
    return '<div class="test"><span>#'.$_GET['i'].'</span><span>'.$matches[2].'</span><span>'.$matches[3].'</span><span>'.$matches[1].'</span></div>';
}

$fileNew = __DIR__.'/fileNew.html';
file_put_contents($fileNew, $textNew);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае есть два варианта, как вы можете попробовать сделать это, и оба они будут зависеть от того, каким редактором вы пользуетесь. Я бы посоветовал использовать либо notepad++, либо PHPStorm, во втором случае это уже не просто текстовый редактор, а полноценная IDE (Integrated Development Environment, Интегрированная среда разработки). Либо любой другой редактор, поддерживающий замену текста и/или мультикурсор.

**Первый вариант**: использовать замену текста, например в notepad++ она вызывается по Ctrl+H, и последовательно заменить все блоки в коде, например первым делом можно поменять `<div class="test" title="Подсказка"><span>` на `<div class="test"><span>`.

Но в этом варианте у вас не получится к примеру сделать автоматически нумерацию (цифры после #), только лишь сделать новую структуру кода.

**Второй вариант**: использовать мультикурсор. Прочитать про него подробнее в случае PHPStorm можно [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/310392/), а в случае с np++ делается это так:

Первым делом эту функцию нужно активировать, в русской версии это делается по такому пути: Опции / Настройки / Правка / Мультиредактирование. Далее с помощью либо функции замены текста, либо самой функции мультикурсора видоизменяете структуру кода, в вашем случае я бы посоветовал использовать замену. И потом делаете нумерацию следующим образом. Выделяете тот кусок текста, после которого должна стоять увеличивающаяся цифра и нажимаете Alt+C, в результате вы увидите окно, где будет два варианта работы, либо "текст для вставки", либо "числа для вставки". Вам нужно будет настроить все вот так:

[image: шаг 1]

Обратите внимание, что цифры будут вставляться там, где у вас расположен курсор во время выделения текста. После чего нажимаете ОК и получаете уже такой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это если вы оставили курсор справа от #. Если вы оставите курсор с левой стороны, то получите такую картину, не запутайтесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Для другого случая помогла нумерация строк